# How to distinguish when a terminal is maximized in terminator?

Tags: linux, gnome-terminator

I use terminator therefore I work with many terminals open in the same tab and sometimes I need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to maximize my field of view. Sometimes I switch tabs to do something else and when I switch back I might have forgot I am on a maximized terminal.

Is there an indicator when you are on a maximized terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Generally a terminal emulator -- because it's emulating a *terminal* -- doesn't "know" anything about the GUI *per se*.  However, you can get the screen size in the terminal with `tput` or (depending on your shell and environment configuration) the `LINES` and `COLS` environment variables:

```
$ tput cols
129
$ tput rows
50
$ printf "%s, %s" "$COLS" "$LINES"
129, 50
```